# How do I display an icon using the Qt::DecorationRole role in a QML TreeView?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I have a TreeView in QML that displays some text using the Qt::DisplayRole role from my custom C++ model.

```
TreeView {
    anchors.fill: parent

    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Name"
        role: "DisplayRole"
    }
    model: BookmarksModel
}
```

And I have a custom model extending from QAbstractItemModel in C++ that returns the proper roles...

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> BookmarksModel::roleNames() const
{
  QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
  roles[Qt::DisplayRole] = "DisplayRole";
  roles[Qt::DecorationRole] = "DecorationRole";
  return roles;
}
```

How do I use the icon that I have stored in Qt::DecorationRole and display it in the QML TreeView row to the left of the text, exactly like it is displayed in a simple QTreeView row?

Thanks.